# Estimative of the measure of the intersection.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $\Sigma_n\subset \Omega$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Sigma_n^c)<\epsilon_n,$ where, $\sum \epsilon_n<\delta$, where $\delta>$ is as small as we want (much smaller than 1).

Can I estimate $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \Sigma_n)$ in terms of the sequence $(\epsilon_n)$ (only)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can at least get a lower bound on the probability:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \Sigma_n\right) &= \mathbb{P}\left(\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \Sigma_n^c\right)^c\right) \\
&= 1-\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \Sigma_n^c\right) \\
&\ge 1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\Sigma_n^c) \\
&\ge 1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \varepsilon_n \\
&\ge 1 - \delta
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you explain me the transition to  the second equality to inequality?

Comment: It's from the countable sub-additivity of measures: $\mathbb{P}(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A_n)$.  We get an equality when the $A_n$ are disjoint, but in general only an inequality.